# Is there a modern translation of the critical text of the Bible into Classical Latin?

Tags: bible-translation, latin

Is there a modern translation of the critical text of the Bible into Classical Latin?  Preferably it would be very literal, and the Apocrypha isn't necessary.

Comment: You're aware that Classical Latin and the Latin in which the older and newer Latin translations (the *Vetus Latina*, *Vulgata*, and *Nova Vulgata*) appear are two distinct varieties of Latin, yes?

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify.

The translation is based on the best original texts available, and the target language is Classical Latin, and the apocrypha are left out. While I am at it, it must also be very literal. Does such a translation exist?

Comment: I doubt that such a thing exists. Bible translations are normally done into languages that will open up the Word to new people. Very few people speak Classical Latin, and those who do generally also speak another, much more common language. Modern *descendants* of Latin, like French or Italian, are an entirely different story. You can easily find modern critical translations into those languages.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Yes, exactly. That's why St. Jerome's Latin translation is called the _Vulgate_ (lit. "vernacular").

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because too specific.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about Christianity.

Comment: The Nova Vulgata is a modern translation and, according to Wikipedia, is intended to "produce a style closer to Classical Latin" as compared to Jerome's Vulgate.  It is also based on modern critical editions of the original texts.